# Finding the private key in Diffie-Hellman

Tags: diffie-hellman

How do I go about finding the shared private key *g^ab*, if I know the prime *p*, primitive root *g*, and the public keys *g^a* and *g^b*?
Assuming that *a*, *b*, *p* and *g* are all very large numbers (~50 digits), it will not be feasible to exhaustively search for *a* and *b* to calculate *g^ab*.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm_records

Comment: To make kelaka's point clearer, 50 digits is about 160 bits - it is easy to find a discrete log of a modulus that size, that is, given $g, g^a \bmod p$, we can find $a$